# PHPWord and images with width

Tags: phpword

```
    $phpWord = new PhpWord();
    $section = $phpWord->addSection();
    \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, '<table style="width:100%"><tr><td><img src="https://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" style="width: 20px;"/></td><td>text</td></tr></table>');

    $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
    $objWriter->save($docx);
```

In this case PhpWord display image with full size, and ignore image width

How fix?

Answer (score 1):

The HTML parser does not seem to understand the css styling put on .
What does work is to pass the width as an attribute

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, '<table style="width:100%"><tr><td><img src="https://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" width="200"/></td><td>text</td></tr></table>');
```

The code above works for me. At least with 0.14, and opening the word document with Word 2016.

Comment: The following works fine for me `$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, '<table style="width:100%"><tr><td><img src="https://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" width="200"/></td><td>text</td></tr></table>');
`